# How can I use torrent using psiphon

Tags: proxy, bittorrent

In my college, I have a proxy server. Now using psiphon, I can bypass proxy. But problem is, torrent is not working with psiphon. If I am using my cyber roam account, also torrent does not work. Is there any solution for the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a way to run torrents on Psiphon, you would also be able to play online games like League of Legends and DoTA.

Here is how it is done:

1. Download Psiphon. Connect to the server closest to you.

   - Go to settings.
   - In settings, go to “Local Proxy Ports”.
   - Enter a desired port number (say 443) in the HTTP/HTTPS section.
   - Apply the settings and reconnect.
2. Download OpenVPN for windows/linux from [here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html).

   - Right click on the OpenVPN GUI running in the taskbar and go to Settings.
   - Go to Proxy tab.
   - Choose Manual Configuration. And choose HTTP Proxy.
   - Enter the address: 127.0.0.1 and Port:443 (which you noted earlier).
   - Click OK.

**Here we made OpenVPN to connect to the server through Psiphon.**

3. There are a lot of free OpenVPN providers which you could find online. Choose any one of then and download the .ovpn config file and place it in "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config"
4. Connect to the server using OpenVPN client running in the Taskbar.
5. That’s it you can play online games and download torrents.

**EDIT: Found an easier way**

Now we don't need Psiphon to connect to internet. I have partially figured out how Psiphon works.

Basically, all it does is establish a VPN through the UDP port 53.

Here is how you should make it work:

1. Google for UDP port 53 OpenVPN servers.
2. Download the .ovpn config for the server which you are going to choose.
3. In OpenVPN GUI:

   - Right click on the OpenVPN GUI running in the taskbar and go to Settings.
   - Go to Proxy tab.
   - Select "Use OpenVPN config file settings". The previous settings will fade away, nothing to worry about it.
4. Make sure that Psiphon is not running.
5. Connect to the server using OpenVPN client running in the Taskbar.
6. This time it may take a few seconds more compared to the previous method.
7. That’s it you can play online games and download torrents.

Comment: Welcome. We like any good answer, no matter how late!

Comment: I have found a way where even Psiphon is not needed for torrents. Gonna make a few edits now

Comment: I have been graduated from college. I don't use psiphon anymore. Hope it answers the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you cannot. [Here](https://www.bestvpn.com/blog/6943/evade-internet-censorship-with-psiphon/) a blogger claims to have spoken with a representative from *psiphon*, who says:

> The VPN mode has its bandwidth deliberately restricted, as Psiphon is keen to be all about censorship evasion , and not about downloading movies.

So, even if you use their VPN, your download rate will be painfully slow, read the blog post above.

Your best solution is to run an OpenVPN server at home or on a cheap VPS (there are some for as little as 2 or three bucks a month), on *TCP port 443*, which is not blocked by just about all proxies and firewalls.

Comment: A lot of work is done with torrent. What if I will not download movies using torrent. :D

Comment: Please guide me to  "run an OpenVPN server at home".

Comment: @learner At home, what's your OS? Windows, Mac, Linux?

Comment: @learner If your OS is Windows, a good guide is https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Easy_Windows_Guide If there is something which you cannot solve, please ask a new question.

Comment: In some countries with limited Internet access (such as Iran), ordinary websites such as Youtube and Facebook (and lots of other online services) are censored. These services are full of video content.

Answer (score 0):

Tribler is better suited to what you have in mind. Its basically a cheap but effective (if not slow) proxy run client. It uses the darkweb to tunnel all torrent traffic. Some say its best to use it with a VPN, but it works just fine on its own. Oh and it has its own built in search engine as well a bonus? Dunno its not the best. You could use Tor for torrent files if paranoid. That or just use i2p with Vuze which has a plugin for i2p, so not only do you tunnel torrent traffic that way. You also make yourself practically invisible and encrypted. No I won't tell you how to do it :)